# Visio DataRecordset Object

Tags: vba, visio

I am messing around with some Visio VBA in 2010 standard.

Any method or property I try with a recordset object gives an error.

```
Public Sub LinkAllRecordsets()
Dim drs As Visio.DataRecordset
Dim dcn As DataConnection
Dim doc As Document
Dim intCount As Integer
    intCount = ThisDocument.DataRecordsets.Count
End Sub
```

The debug halts at the intCount = line, giving a generic "this operation is not supported in Microsoft Visio Standard 2010".

Is there a way I can get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way! DataRecordsets are supported only in **Visio 20xx (2007+) Professional** or **Visio Plan 2** editions!
[DataRecordset object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.datarecordset)

Answer (score 0):

Nuts!

Thanks for the information.

Comment: You can ask, Can you provide a clearer question?, instead of rude answer.